# Bokeh Static HTML files taking 10 mins to load - Performance Improvements

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, bokeh

I have some static HTML files created using Bokeh - they are no more than 2 MB. (This can increase up to 5 MB).. They take forever to load and in most cases do not load. What can i do to speed this up? I am using the latest browsers - chrome, firefox etc on both Ubuntu and Windows. Creation of these files are quite quick.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>XXXXXX</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.4.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.4.min.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Bokeh.set_log_level("info");
</script>
    <style>
      html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      body {
        width: 90%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: auto;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="bk-root">
        <div class="bk-plotdiv" id="503165fc-0c33-4335-b1f2-f0cc6beb5370"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
      var fn = function() {
        Bokeh.safely(function() {
          var docs_json = {"f23fa3d5-8abc-40b1-9ff6-f129bed85cc4":{"roots":{"references"
```

lots of json

```
          Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);
        });
      };
      if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
      else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
    })();

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Example output?  If it's too large you can try a pastebin service.  Also, some Python code example from your HTML generator?

Comment: Well, maybe `lots of json` is the problem -- too many objects for the browser to handle. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186494/if-the-bokeh-has-many-chart-output-file-is-very-heavy-and-system-slow#22189513

Comment: I think there is at most 10k data points to plot?

Comment: I don't think there's any way out of this except real benchmark and profiling.  On Firefox you can open `about:memory` to inspect memory usage. There are 10k points, each with their paths, shapes and perhaps transparency, etc., so the resource demanded could be very high.  Perhaps down-sampling the data to be displayed might help.

Comment: When you have a lot of data to display, you might want to first load the page without the data, and bring the data later on upon request that wan display something linke "loading...". Using a bokeh server app could make things easier, but since you are loading a static html page, you could include `XMLHttpRequest` inside `CustomJS` callback functions